# Remote Desktop not working with Windows Azure Cloud Service. "Legacy plugin RemoteAccess is found in role"

Tags: visual-studio, azure, remote-desktop

I'm trying to publish an Azure Cloud Service but I keep getting this error - 'Legacy plugin RemoteAccess is found in role . Please remove the import from Service Definition file to use the Extension.'

I have the following lines in my csdef -

```
 <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
 <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
```

and the following lines in my cscfg -

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="true" />
 <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountUsername" value="username" />
 <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="password" />
 <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountExpiration" value="2016-06-03T23:59:59.0000000-07:00" />
 <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.Enabled" value="true" />
```

and

```
 <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption" thumbprint="thumbprint" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
```

From what I've read that should be sufficient. I also haven't found anything about a 'Remote Access' plugin being deprecated.

I also tried deleting these lines and publishing - that works fine but I'm unable to use Remote Desktop. I get the error "The specified user name does not exist. Verify the username and try logging in again. If the problem continues, contact your system administrator or technical support." when trying to log in.

Comment: Which Azure SDK Version are you using?

Comment: I have both the October 2012 release and v2.0 installed.

Comment: I deleted the October 2012 release, still no luck.

Comment: Very odd - Remote desktop works fine in the staging environment.

Comment: Did you solved the problem without deleting RemoteAccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't have parts of your username in your password for some reason.

I also ran into credential caching problems which is solved here - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ae35ca/windows-azure-fixing-reconnect-remote-desktop-error-the-specified-user-name-does-not-exist-verif/

Comment: Did you also have to delete those lines?

Answer (score 3):

In case someone stumbles upon this page from a search engine, we had the same problem when doing a package deployment of a Cloud Service. We were using Visual Studio 2019 and Azure SDK 2.9.

After reading [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop-visual-studio), we removed all these lines from our `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file:

```
<Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
<Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
```

and these lines from all our `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg` files, in the `<ConfigurationSettings>` section:

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="true" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountUsername" value="..." />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="..." />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountExpiration" value="..." />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.Enabled" value="true" />
```

and in the `Certificates` section:

```
<Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption" thumbprint="..." thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
```

Then we enabled the RDP access [via the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop-new-portal#configure-remote-desktop-from-the-azure-portal). Once enabled, the access stays valid even after deployment updates.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `BadResponse` and the message returned can be quite ambiguous. In my case the issue was related to a missing certificate from the configuration section and got resolved by deleting the instance from the cloud service and redeploying. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue "Legacy plugin RemoteAccess is found in role" from last one month and i tried all solutions available over forums.

In my case i have fixed this issue by updating Visual Studio from 2015 to 2017 as one of my colleague was using VS 2017 for deployment and i was using VS 2015.

Thank you.